# Execute JavaScript code in popup for Mapbox?

Tags: javascript, mapbox, popup, mapbox-gl-js, html-popup

I'm trying to embed tweets into the popups for a map I've made in Mapbox. The text of the tweets is displaying properly, but not the styling — the embed code contains a script tag to load a widget for styling, and I would guess that this is not being executed by the "sethtml" function. How can I execute the JavaScript when the popup is opened in Mapbox?

I've run into this problem in Leaflet before, and solved it with the following function.

```
map.on('popupopen', function(e) {
    $.getScript("https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js");
});
```

I admit I'm new to Mapbox, but I thought this script would also work for mapbox GL JS. I have the following (not working) code for GL JS:

```
// add markers to map
geojson.features.forEach(function(marker) {

  // create a HTML element for each feature
  var el = document.createElement('div');
  el.className = 'marker';

//get JS widget and move marker down
  map.on('popupopen', function(e) {
    $.getScript("https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js");
    var px = map.project(e.popup._latlng);
    px.y -= e.popup._container.clientHeight/1.5;
    map.panTo(map.unproject(px),{animate: true});
});

  // make a marker for each feature and add to the map
  new mapboxgl.Marker(el)
    .setLngLat(marker.geometry.coordinates)
    .setPopup(new mapboxgl.Popup({ offset: 5 }) // add popups
    .setHTML(marker.properties.Embed + marker.properties.Name))
    .addTo(map);

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've figured this out; leaving the question up in case the solution helps anyone else:

```
 new mapboxgl.Marker(el)
    .setLngLat(marker.geometry.coordinates)
    .setPopup(new mapboxgl.Popup({ offset: 5 }) // add popups
    .on('open', function(e) {
      $.getScript("https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js");
    })
    .setHTML(marker.properties.Embed + marker.properties.Name))
    .addTo(map);
```

Comment: If this answers your question, please mark it as solution (click the check mark next to the answer).